Geometric Brownian Motion vs Lognormal (Monte Carlo)
I am a bit confused. I thought that simulating stock prices via the GBM model is equivalent to drawing returns from a lognormal distribution.
In particular, consider the following Python code, which showcases both approaches I am referring to. It yields slightly different results. My questions are: Why is that so - what is the difference here?
EDIT: When I do not transform the standard deviation like I do in approach 2, both approaches yield a much more similar result. However, I was of the opinion that the lognormal standard deviation =/= the normal standard deviation and hence the transformation. What am I missing here? I appended this code below the original code (Implementation 2).
# IMPLEMENTATION 1
import numpy as np

# Parameters
mu = 0.05  # annual return
sigma = 0.2  # annual volatility
S0 = 100  # initial stock price
dt = 1/252  # daily time step
years = 5 # years
total_steps = 252 * years # total steps
M = 10000  # number of simulations

# Method 1: Geometric Brownian Motion
np.random.seed(42)
St1 = np.exp(
    (mu - sigma ** 2 / 2) * dt
    + sigma * np.random.normal(0, np.sqrt(dt), size=(total_steps, M))
)
final_prices1 = S0 * np.cumprod(St1, axis=0)

# Method 2: Direct Log-Normal
np.random.seed(42)
# Transforming the parameters to those of the underlying normally distributed log returns
norm_sigma = np.sqrt(np.log((sigma / (1 + mu)) ** 2 + 1))
norm_mu = np.log(1 + mu) - 0.5 * norm_sigma ** 2
returns2 = np.random.lognormal(
    mean=norm_mu * dt,
    sigma=norm_sigma * np.sqrt(dt),
    size=(total_steps, M)
) - 1
final_prices2 = S0 * np.cumprod(1 + returns2, axis=0)

# Compare statistics
print("Method 1 Final Price - Mean:", np.mean(final_prices1[-1]))
print("Method 2 Final Price - Mean:", np.mean(final_prices2[-1]))
print("Method 1 Final Price - Std:", np.std(final_prices1[-1]))
print("Method 2 Final Price - Std:", np.std(final_prices2[-1]))


# IMPLEMENTATION 2
import numpy as np

# Parameters
mu = 0.05  # annual return
sigma = 0.2  # annual volatility
S0 = 100  # initial stock price
dt = 1/252  # daily time step
years = 5 # years
total_steps = 252 * years # total steps
M = 10000  # number of simulations

# Method 1: Geometric Brownian Motion
np.random.seed(42)
St1 = np.exp(
    (mu - sigma** 2 / 2) * dt
    + sigma * np.random.normal(0, np.sqrt(dt), size=(total_steps, M))
)
final_prices1 = S0 * np.cumprod(St1, axis=0)

# Method 2: Direct Log-Normal
np.random.seed(42)
norm_mu = np.log(1 + mu) - 0.5 * sigma ** 2
returns2 = np.random.lognormal(
    mean=norm_mu * dt,
    sigma=sigma * np.sqrt(dt),
    size=(total_steps, M)
) - 1
final_prices2 = S0 * np.cumprod(1+returns2, axis=0)

# Compare statistics
print("Method 1 Final Price - Mean:", np.mean(final_prices1[-1]))
print("Method 2 Final Price - Mean:", np.mean(final_prices2[-1]))
print("Method 1 Final Price - Std:", np.std(final_prices1[-1]))
print("Method 2 Final Price - Std:", np.std(final_prices2[-1]))


Hi: In the first method, when you compute final price, you do cumprod on the returns but you need to A) do cumprod on 1 + the return or B)  sum the log prices and divide by $n$ and then exponentiate the final result..

@mark leeds I disagree. This is the exact implementation of the GBM model. Notice that I exponentiate (mu-sigma ** 2/2)* dt ... I get values that are very close to method two, but different. When I do not transform the std_dev in method 2, the values are exactly the same.

When you calc ST1, what is it ? If it's the log return, the you gotta cumprod ( 1 +  log return). If it's something else, then I'm wrong.

It is (1 + return). Also, if it was the log return, I would not have to cumprod it, but to e**(cumsum (1+it)).

My question essentially boils down to: Why is the arithmetic return volatility = logarithmic return volatility in the GBM model. There are no coding errors or anything related.

if it's (1 + log return) already, then I am wrong.

It is not 1 + log return. It is 1 + return, which is correct and as intended.

My bad. I'm confused and I gotta roll but I'lllook at it later. And you are right, that cumprod should always be on the return. I work with small returns so I tend to use them arithmetic and log interchangeably.

Hi utopia: apologies for all the mistakes and starts and stops. Let me see if I can finally understand it.  In the first method, you write the SDE for the log returns which has the extra drift term. Then you take the exp of that. That gives you returns. But then you  do cumprod  on those returns. Where is the 1 + coming from ? I don't see it. Thanks.

Assuming St1 is correct, I don't follow your method in Method II. You want to generate from the lognormal directly. So, why not use the mean and standard deviation of the associated normal to do that ? The (1+mu) factors in the mean and sd  are not familiar to me.  I apologize for not being able to help. Hopefully someone else can.

No worries. And I do exactly that: mu and sigma are the mean and the volatility of the lognormally distributed returns. I transform these to the mean and volatility of the normally distributed log returns in method two, and feed them to the lognormal() function, which requires these as inputs.

And 1+ implicitly follows from the exponentiating. This is just a mathematical fact. You can verify that yourself doing a simple numerical example.

Formally, both methods look correct. Remarks: 1. you have been running this with 10 million simulations. On my computer this requires memory of over 93 Gbyte which is impossible. How did you do it? 2. When I change the seed all your means and stdevs change. What makes you think any of those is "correct" and not subject to Monte Carlo noise?

You should probably describe more precisely what you mean by "When I do not transform the standard deviation like I do in approach 2...". Best to modify the program accordingly.

@KurtG. I appended the second code implementation. The number of simulations was too excessive, you are right. I adjusted it. Method 1 nearly always yields a higher mean return, irrespective of the seed chosen. Implementation 2 yields much closer results it seems. I think I am misunderstanding the volatility term. Here for example, the author explicitly sets sigma of log returns = sigma of returns. This is different from my method 2 and possible what I am getting wrong. https://gregorygundersen.com/blog/2024/04/13/simulating-gbm/

Ok. With the second implementation (directly feeding the same sigma into np.random.lognormal as you did in np.random.normal) the results agree within unavoidable Monte Carlo noise. You can test a few more different seeds to verify that. This close agreement tells  us what format of volatility np.random.lognormal is expecting to do the same thing you did with the other function.

@KurtG. I agree. By transforming the volatility as I do in implementation 1, I implicitly treat sigma as the vola of returns. However, the GBM requires the vola of log returns. I hence have to either transform sigma in both approaches (sigma=vola of returns), or neither (sigma=vola of log returns), I think.

I don't think so. np.random.normal makes totally transparent that you simulate $S_t=S_0\exp(\sigma W_t+\mu t -\sigma^2t/2),.$ The log return of this is $\sigma W_t+\mu t-\sigma^2t/2$ and obviously has the vola $\sigma,.$ If this does not convince you you could even add a little code to calculate the vol of the log returns of your simulations :)

Another sanity check you could do is to compare the final mean to the theoretical mean $S_0e^{\mu t}$ and the final standard deviation to the theoretical one $S_0e^{\mu t}\sqrt{e^{\sigma^2t}-1},.$

utopia: I'll stay out of this because I already caused a traffic jam but thanks for setting me straight on exp of lognormal. It results in the ratio, $S_{t2}/S_{t1}$  which is definitely (1 + ). Thanks again. I'll just listen and learn.

utopia: I will phrase this as "take a look" and see if it matters. When you calculate St1, you are calculating ratios of prices which is definitely (1 + return) which I was absolutely ignorant of. But that's an arithmetic return so you are cumproding arithmetic returns. I'm not sure if that matters in your case but maybe that's causing some issue in your calculations. I mean it's fine to cumprod arithmetic returns, assuming that's your intention but maybe it isn't ?

my point of above is that you could do 1 + cumsum(log(St1)) and that would give you the log analogue of what you calculated, but I don't know what the goal is

I will rephrase the question and create a new thread to be more precise about what my issue is.

Method 1 uses
$$
S = S_0 \prod_{i=1}^N\exp\left( \left(\mu - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2  \right)\Delta t  + \sigma \sqrt{\Delta t} x_i \right)
$$
where $x_i \in \texttt{np.random.normal}(0,\sqrt{\Delta t})$.
Method 2 should use
$$
S = S_0 \prod_{i=1}^N z_i
$$
where $z_i \in \texttt{np.random.lognormal}((\mu - 0.5 \sigma^2)\Delta t,\sigma \sqrt{\Delta t})$.
In your version of Method 2 you have
$$
S = S_0 \prod_{i=1}^N (1+r_i)
$$
where $r_i$ is what you call $\texttt{returns2}$. You model this as a lognormal variable; but clearly $z_i=1+r_i$ is a lognormal variable; and if $r_i$ is a lognormal variable, $z_i$ is not a lognormal variable.

Thanks for your response, but I disagree. I model z as a lognormal variable, just as you suggest. np.random.lognormal takes the underlying normal parameters as input and spits out lognormally distributed variable realizations, which are z in your definition - notice how I substract 1 after simulating the variable.

@utopia your whole approach is very patchy. What is the point of subtracting one and then adding it? Based on the documentation for $\texttt{np.random.lognormal}$, $\texttt{mean}=(\mu - 0.5 \sigma^2) \Delta t$.
